# Forward rate example, switching the investment.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I need explanation regarding forward rates for the following specific example.

> A zero coupon with spot rate $s_0(1)=.08$ and $s_0(2)=.09$ are available.
>
> a), Smith borrows $1$ and is obliged to pay back $1.08$ at the end of the year. Using that money he reinvests and purchases a bond for $1$, which at the end of the second year he receives $1.1881$.
>
> b), Jones borrows $1$ and is obliged to pay back $1.881$ two years from now.  Using that money he reinvests and purchases a bond for $1$, which at the end of the first year he receives $1.08$
>
> Find the forward rate for both situation.

The book I am working on suggests that these two answers are supposed to be the same, but I intuitively think that case b) would lose money...

can someone explain this to me?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume $s_0(2) = 0.09$, as a $90\%$ interest rate is rather high. ;)

Comment: Also, which forward rate are you referring to? When does it start, when does it begin?... how long is it?

Comment: I assume @hyg17 is referring to the forward rate from t=1 to t=2. With that being said, why do you think the forward rates should be different? I don't want to answer this too much for you, but I could help explain the flaw in your logic.

Comment: >Clarinetist thanks, I fixed it.  And yes, I did mean the forward rate from t=1 to t=2.  I should have mentioned it for clarification..


$$_$$

>mardat Thanks for the clarification. Could you explain if you don't mind? I want to have as much information from others because I am self studying this material and don't have much to refer to.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they borrowed to buy the bond is immaterial.  At the end of the first year, Smith is $-1.08$ and will have $1.1881$ at the end of year 2.  He promises his creditor the $1.1881$, an interest rate of $\frac {1.1881}{1.08}$  At the end of the first year, Jones is $+1.08$.  He needs $1.1881$ at the end of year 2, so he needs an interest rate of $\frac {1.1881}{1.08}$ to satisfy that.